# Cron job without crontab in linux

Tags: linux, cron, moodle

I have moodle installation on linux platform.
I want to set up a cron job for sending e-mails to users.
I've read about using crontab program and configuring it.

But according to my client requirements I want to execute it WITHOUT using crontab.

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Nope. Crontab is the file that describes jobs that cron runs. Without it, you get nothing.

Comment: Maybe using `at` command might help.... But for periodic things, use `crontab` & `cron`

Comment: I glanced over the man pages so `cron` = regularly once in a while. `at` = once. If your client is prohibiting you from doing things, maybe he also has something in mind on how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I got the idea. Thanks a lot..

Comment: For actions that need to happen at relatively standard intervals, most distributions provide something like `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, etc.  You can just drop an executable into these directories and it will run with the given frequency, no mucking about with crontab required.

Comment: Why does the client need to avoid using cron?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `while`,  `loop`?

Example:

```
while true;
do echo "Hello" ;
sleep 100;
done &
```

So you can enter your command / email script after `do`, or you can make a script for email process and called after do,

Note: kindly add end & symbol, so this will get execute in background.

Thanks.